# c++ How to test whether a certain bit of memory in the heap is free?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, heap-memory

I have some code:

```
int *ip = new int;

*ip = 42;
cout << *ip << endl;
cout << ip << endl;

delete ip;
cout << *ip << endl;
cout << ip << endl;
```

The output is:

```
42
0x100105400
42
0x100105400
```

From the value of the pointer and the value on the memory where it pointed to, I think I can't know whether the bit of memory in the heap pointed by `ip` is free?

I know that if I were to add `delete ip;` again after my code, the compiler will throw an error. That will be a good evidence that the memory is free.

But, how can I test whether it's free peacefully, so that I can use it as a condition to decide further operations in my code?

Comment: `cout << *ip << endl;` is undefined behavior. You are dereferenceing a dangling pointer. The probably only way to safely test is to set `ip` to `nullptr` after the `delete`.

Comment: Do you want to implement your own GarbageCollector?!? You need to know your pointers and you need to know, which memory needs to be freed. For that, the use of smart pointers would be very helpful, because they clean up memory on their own. For the thing, you are trying to do, a macro could be helpful, which deletes the pointer and sets the pointer automatically to nullptr after deletion. Then you have the possibility to check ip != nullptr before referencing. But I tell you ... smart pointers are the way to go ;)

Comment: @Mr.Yellow Good to know. But that's not what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some design issues if your code depends on whether specific memory is free or not. But, if you indeed want to test, you can overload `operator new` and `operator delete` (and their corresponding array/class versions) so they keep track of which memory locations are allocated in some global data structure available to your program. Here is some toy example ([live on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/90dADP)) which defines a placement `new` that keeps track of what memory (and size) was allocated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<void*, std::size_t> memory; // globally allocated memory map
struct tag {}; // tag for placement new's so we don't overload the global ones

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const tag&)
{
    void* addr = malloc(size);
    memory[addr] = size;
    return addr;
}

void* operator new[](std::size_t size, const tag&) // for arrays
{
    return operator new(size, tag());
}

void operator delete(void *p) noexcept
{
    memory.erase(p);
    free(p);
}

void operator delete[](void *p) noexcept // for arrays
{
    operator delete(p);
}

void display_memory()
{
    std::cout << "Allocated heap memory: " << std::endl;
    for (auto && elem : memory)
    {
        std::cout << "\tADDR: " << elem.first << " "
                  << "SIZE: "  << elem.second << std::endl;
    }
}

bool is_allocated(void* p)
{
    return (memory.find(p) != memory.end());
}

int main()
{
    int *p = new(tag()) int[10];
    char *c = new(tag()) char;

    // test if p is allocated
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Allocated: "
              << is_allocated(p) << std::endl;

    // display the allocated memory
    display_memory();

    // remove p
    delete[] p;

    // test again if p is allocated
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Allocated: "
              << is_allocated(p) << std::endl;

    display_memory();

    // remove c
    delete c;

    display_memory();
}
```

**EDIT:** I realized that there may be some issues with the code above. In the function

```
void operator delete(void *p) noexcept
{
    memory.erase(p);
    free(p);
}
```

`memory.erase(p)` calls also `operator delete`, so you may end up with some nasty recursion (for some reason, the code above only enters the recursion once). A fix is to write a custom allocator for the `std::map memory` that uses `malloc/free` instead of global `operator new/delete`.

Comment: Why go to all that trouble when you can just set the pointers to `nullptr` once deleted?

Comment: Because that's not, what TMI is looking for :-/

Comment: @Brett I agree setting pointers to `nullptr` does it, however what if one forgets? I gave this example mainly to make the point that in C++ almost everything is possible.

Comment: `void foo(int* p){if(rand()%2){ delete p; p = nullptr;}} int* a = new int; foo(a);` Now `a` may be a dangling pointer, and foo has no way of setting it to `nullptr`. Also, the caller has no way, too, since it doesn't know if the memory pointed too was deleted or not. Of course, the best solution is using a smart pointer. The point is: No, setting pointers to `nullptr` after deleting is not a good solution.

Comment: @vsoftco Thank you! Inspiring~

Comment: @Brett An allocated address can be stored in an arbitrary number of places which do not know of each other. Setting one of them to the null pointer does not solve anything for the others. vsoftco's implementation of a central book keeping facility does, though.

Comment: @PeterSchneider This is a very good point that I didn't think of, indeed you can have multiple pointers pointing to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

> But, how can I test whether it's free peacefully, so that I can use it as a condition to decide further operations in my code?

Freeing memory doesn't change the value of the pointer, and will not necessarily change the memory it points to (which you should not try to access once it's freed anyway).

What you should do is set the pointer to `nullptr` when deleting it, then you can check if it's `nullptr` or not to see if it's been freed.

Example:

```
int* ip = new int;

*ip = 42;

delete ip;
ip = nullptr;

// ...

if (ip) {
    delete ip;
    ip = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Brett, check my comment on vsoftco's answer.

Comment: @CássioRenan if a function is passed a pointer to some memory then frees it, that is really bad design. If you really did need to do that, just dereference the pointer again, e.g. `void foo(int** p){if(rand()%2){ delete *p; *p = nullptr;}} int* a = new int; foo(&a);` - now the caller can check if `a` is nullptr or not.

Comment: It was an example to illustrate that some memory address may be pointed to at several different places in the same program, and setting all of those pointers to nullptr isn't always plausible and certainly not scalable. "Fixing" the example won't fix the problem.

Comment: @CássioRenan now that is really, really bad design. If you had a situation like that and weren't using `std::shared_ptr`, you should be shot

Comment: If bad design were the point, you should be using a `std::unique_ptr` in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a link to Doug Lea's free store implementation page: http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html.

In the first diagram, the memory layout, you can see that the user data of each allocation chunk is preceded by bookkeeping information which includes an "in-use" flag. The chunks form a linked list: From a given chunk one can reach all chunks after that (and, actually, before that as well).

Knowing data size and alignment requirements one can guess on a given system where that information may be relative to the returned pointer; on my x86_64-pc-cygwin the status bytes are the 8 bytes before the returned address, and the "in use" flag is the 2-bit of the first byte.

While that looks promising, there is a catch: Poking around I could see that a delete() coalescs adjacent chunks so that the bookkeeping information is only valid at the beginning of the fused chunks: If you have two pointers p1, p2 which point to memory in the free store which was allocated in sequence, and you delete in order again, the memory at p2's bookkeeping location is not refreshed to reflect that p2 was deallocated. Instead, the bookkeeping region before *p1* now indicates that the following memory chunk has the size of the single chunks combined.

In order to find out whether the memory a given pointer points to has been freed, one would have to traverse the linked list of memory blocks, presumably starting at a dummy object which was allocated before anything else. Certainly possible, but not desirable and not robust. @vsoftco's idea is much better.

Last not least: People who always return int from main will likely bemoan that all of this is UB. They are right.